# Doctrine MongoDB ODM: how to get the bin_md5 version of the @Id

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, doctrine-odm

With Doctrine ODM (MongoDB) it is possible to use the annotation `Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations\Id` to set the ID of a document.

As I want to use an hash as ID, I've set my document this way:

```php
class WebResource
{
    /**
     * @ODM\Id(strategy="NONE", type="bin_md5")
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $hash;
    ...
}
```

This configuration transforms an hash like `774a0f33ede410cde2d785e2d9e52561` to the `_id: 'Nzc0YTBmMzNlZGU0MTBjZGUyZDc4NWUyZDllNTI1NjE='`.

Now, when I get the `$hash` from the document, I get the value `774a0f33ede410cde2d785e2d9e52561`.

This makes impossible for me to use a query like this in MongoDB Compass:

```
{"_id": "774a0f33ede410cde2d785e2d9e52561"}
```

This query, in fact, will always return no value as the actual ID is `Nzc0YTBmMzNlZGU0MTBjZGUyZDc4NWUyZDllNTI1NjE=`.

How can I find a document by its ID, having only its hash not still transformed?

I've tried a lot of approaches:

1. Using `md5()` php function;
2. Using `(new Binary($resource->getHash(), Binary::TYPE_MD5))->getData()`
3. Using `new \MongoBinData($resource->getHash(), \MongoBinData::MD5)`

Nothing of those tries seems to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Nzc0YTBmMzNlZGU0MTBjZGUyZDc4NWUyZDllNTI1NjE=` is just base64 encoded `774a0f33ede410cde2d785e2d9e52561`

```
echo -n '774a0f33ede410cde2d785e2d9e52561' | base64
```

and use the result in compas

Comment: So simple -.-' Thank you!